# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n - \sqrt {{n^2} - n} )$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n - \sqrt {{n^2} - n})$$

My try:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n - \sqrt {{n^2} - n} ) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n - \sqrt {{n^2}(1 - \frac{1}{n}} )\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n - n\sqrt {(1 - \frac{1}{n}})\right)$$

$$\sqrt {(1 - \frac{1}{n}} ) \to 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n - n\sqrt {(1 - \frac{1}{n}})\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (n - n) = 0$$

Ok, it's not correct. In articles i found method:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{{(n - \sqrt {{n^2} - n} )(n + \sqrt {{n^2} - n} )}}{{n + \sqrt {{n^2} - n} }} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{{n + \sqrt {{n^2} - n} }} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{{1 + \sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{n}}}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Why the second method is valid, but the first one not? Whats difference?

Comment: just shooting, I don't think you can take an isolated look at the factor $\sqrt{1-\frac1{n}}$, but you have to inspect the whole term $n\sqrt{1-\frac1{n}}$ which does not converge.

Comment: The first method is invalid: just because $\sqrt{1-\tfrac1n} \to 1$, doesn't mean that $n\sqrt{1-\tfrac1n}$ is very close to $n$.  Try applying the same logic to $\lim_n (n - n(1-\tfrac1n))$: you would still get $n-n = 0$ which is very false because $n - n(1-\tfrac1n) = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that inside a limit, you can't substitute an expression with the limit it is approaching. The expresion $\sqrt{1-1/n}$ does go to $1$, but it does so at a slow pace, while the expression $n$ goes to infinity at a certain pace as well, so $n\sqrt{1-1/n}$ does not necessarily grow arbitrarily close to $n$.

Answer (score 3):

> $$\lim (n - n\sqrt {(1 - \frac{1}{n}} )) = \lim (n - n) = 0$$

This is not correct. If $n$ goes to infinity, all $n$'s go to infinity, not just the one in $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$. Here it's as if you fixed the first two $n$'s of your expression, and let the third one go to infinity.

So with this method you would get $\infty - 1\times\infty$, which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this step:

$$\lim (n - n\sqrt {(1 - \frac{1}{n}} )) = \lim (n - n)$$

How do you justify this? You need to take the limit of everything all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[n-\sqrt{n^2-n}\right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[n-n\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]$

Now Using $\displaystyle (1+x)^{n} = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+.....$

So we get $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[n-n\left(1-\frac{n}{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2n^2}+.......\infty\right)\right] = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The question wasn't to figure out the limit, which he/she did, the question was what's wrong with that computation.

Comment: actually he/she did not expand $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$  in a proper manner, Thats why i have expanded and solve it.

Comment: Maybe you should comment on *why* that computation was incorrect, rather than just offering a correct computation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your method is wrong:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{n(1-\sqrt{1-\frac1{n}}}=0\times \infty
$$

Which is undefined